# Spring - webjar paths and websocketing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, webjars

Just a few basic questions about using webjars :

1. I found my webjar on https://www.webjars.org/. I added it to my Maven Pom. Now i need to use it in my html file. How do i find the path so i can import it?

example: I copied this dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3-1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And in my html file i did:

```
 <script src="/webjars/sockjs-client/sockjs.min.js"></script>
```

When i open my page in the console i get:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/webjars/sockjs-client/sockjs.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

So, how do i find the proper path?

2. The second question is about websocketing. I have been following this tutorial:https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring

In it, it says add this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>

</dependency>
```

But then in the html file imports this:

```
<script src="./js/sockjs-0.3.4.js"></script>
<script src="./js/stomp.js"></script>
```

Do sockjs and stomp come along with the dependency mention above ? Is there a reason for that path or is it becouse its a part of something like angular or react?

3.I saw someone add a config like this :

```
@Configuration

public class WebJarConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
    }
}
```

What does this do ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi! I'm stuck here with the same problem. Did you solve it? Thanks!